# PowerMockito Enum in Switch Statement throwing NPE

Tags: java, enums, nullpointerexception, switch-statement, powermockito

I'm testing a class with PowerMockRunner which retrieves a `value` ENUM from a static method in a helper class. A null pointer is thrown when this `value` ENUM is passed into a SWITCH statement in the classUnderTest.

I've debugged and can see the ENUM is set correctly (name, type, ordinal all as expected) so am unsure as to why the NPE is thrown. Anybody encounter similar issue?

Note: PowerMockito is required as classUnderTest includes calls to private methods. Below is complete example with a lot of code (unrelated to issue) removed. Comments added at point where ENUM is set and NPE is thrown

ClassUnderTest:

```
public class TestService extends BaseXAServiceBean
{

@Override
public ValueObject runExecute(ValueObject param) throws RemoteException, ServiceException
{
    try
    {
        ValueEnum value = ValueServiceHelper.getValueType(param1(),
                    param2());
        // value populated successfully with ENUM at this point         


        // NPE thrown when value is passed into below switch
        switch (value)
        {
            case VALUE1:
            {                       
                // logic here...
                break;
            }

            case VALUE2:
            {                       
                // logic here...
                break;
            }

            case VALUE3:
            {                       
                // logic here...
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (ServiceException e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new ServiceException(e, AppErrorCodes.INT.SL06, AppErrorCodes.SL06.E04);
    } finally {
        // clean up
    }
}
}
```

Helper Class with static method:

```
public class ValueServiceHelper
{
public static ValueEnum getValueType(String param1, String param2) throws ServiceException
    {
        ValueEnum retVal = ValueEnum.VALUE3;

        // proxy is mocked
        ProductProxy proxy = ProxyFactory.createFactory("1").getProductProxy();

        try
        {
            if (proxy.isValue1(param2))
            {
                retVal = ValueEnum.VALUE1;
            }
            else if (proxy.isValue2(param2))
            {
                retVal = ValueEnum.VALUE2;
            }

        }
        return retVal;
    }
}
```

Test Class:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ProxyFactory.class})
public class ValueTest {

@Spy
@InjectMocks
private TestService service = new TestService();

@Mock
private ProxyFactory proxyFactory;

@Mock
private Proxy proxy;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    PowerMockito.mockStatic(ProxyFactory.class);
}

@Test
public void testSuccess() throws Exception {
    // given

    // when
PowerMockito.when(ProxyFactory.createFactory("1")).thenReturn(proxyFactory);
PowerMockito.when(proxyFactory.getProductProxy()).thenReturn(proxy);
    PowerMockito.when(proxy.isValue1(param2)).thenReturn(true);
    PowerMockito.when(proxy.isValue2(param2)).thenReturn(true);
    service.runExecute(request);        

    // then

}
}
```

Comment: You need to provide a complete, verifiable example. There is not enough information here to answer.

Comment: Updated now to include complete example....

Comment: [Perhaps related?](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/issues/394) See if using an `if` statement solves the problem.

Comment: Thanks, looks like the same problem. I've tested with an if statement and it works fine. However as I'm building a retrospective test for existing code I'd rather not make any change to the classUnderTest.

Comment: Unfortunately there are a lot of gotchas like that with PowerMock that I've encountered. Switches are particularly problematic, even with code coverage tools like Jacoco. Looks like that issue has been around for at least two years so it's unlikely to be fixed. The issues are probably related to the generated Java bytecode, but I don't have enough knowledge on the subject to say if it's fixable.

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with PowerMock that has existed [since at least 2015](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/issues/394). The only way to fix it that I'm aware of is to use `if` statements instead of a `switch`.